# Python modifies unicode identifiers?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Python 3.8 supports using a limited set of non-ASCII Unicode characters in identifiers. So, it seems that it is valid to use  as a character in an identifier.

However, something is wrong...

**Problem**

```
def f():
    print(f'{=}')

f(1)
f(=2)
f(**{'': 3})
```

The first two calls are fine, but the third fails:

```
=1
=2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sigma.py", line 24, in <module>
    f(**{'': 3})
TypeError: f() got an unexpected keyword argument ''
```

**Analysis**

Let's see what is actually going on:

```
def f2(**kw):
    for name, value in kw.items():
        print(f'{name}={value}     {ord(name)=}')
f2(=2)
f2(**{'': 3})
```

It prints:

```
Σ=2     ord(name)=931
=3     ord(name)=120506
```

I called it with  both times, but it was changed to the very similar *simpler* Σ in the first call.

It seems that an argument named  (U+1D6BA) is implicitly renamed to Σ (U+03A3), and in every call to the function, argument  is also implicitly renamed to Σ, except if it is passed as `**kwargs`.

**The Questions**

Is this a bug? It does not look like it is accidental. Is it documented? Is there a set of *true* characters and a list of *alias* characters available somewhere?

Comment: Nice find. Filed a bug?

Comment: The documentation about [Identifiers and keywords](https://docs.python.org/3.8/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers) states: "All identifiers are converted into the normal form NFKC while parsing; comparison of identifiers is based on NFKC.". That could be the reason.

Comment: @Matthias Yeah that seems to be it. You can reproduce the behaviour without kwargs: ` = 0; Σ` -> `0`. And just to confirm the normal form, `unicodedata.normalize('NFKC', '')` -> `'Σ'`.

Answer (score 1):

I think this happens because of the way Python handles characters.
If you set a variable using one of your provided sigma letters: Σ or , you can also access it with the other one. Knowing that both these snippets work:

```py
>>> Σ = 5
>>> 
5
```

```py
>>>  = 5
>>> Σ
5
```

You can see in `globals()` it is assigned to Σ (ord: 931)
My guess is Python modifies the character before performing a variable lookup.
[Similar discussion here, posted by me in github/wtfpython](https://github.com/satwikkansal/wtfpython/issues/280)